# Utilizing c++ from c#

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling, unmarshalling, unmanaged-memory

I currently have some c++ code which processes 'char ***myArray' much faster than any other method for string comparison.

I'm also wrapping my c++ into a DLL and calling functions from a C# GUI which uses a 'DataTable'.

I'm curious how I go about passing my 'DataTable' data accross to my 'char ***myArray'.

Interface.cs:

```
DataTable table
```

cppFunctions.cpp:

```
int CheckColumn(char ***myArray)
{
    int k = 0;
    double weight = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < RowCount; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < RowCount; j++)
        {
            weight = nGram(myArray[i][colNum], myArray[j][colNum], 3);
            k++;
        }
    }
    return k;
}
```

If I pass int, double, string, or any simple value across it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

DataTable is part of the .NET FCL, so you cannot pass it.  The reason int, string, etc work is that they are primitives.  You could serialize / de-serialize the DataTable.

Alternatively, you could use marshalling:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235266.aspx

Comment: Your suggestions are good and kindof what I've been looking into since my post. I would in theory like to be able to create char *** myarray in C# which would solve my issue. From there I could always format it into a DataTable for display.

I really don't like the idea of creating a file between the two and I know this is a very common practice. I guess I'll have to investigate marshalling a little more but my thought was that if I am running a DLL and marshaling data that it still would not make it to my C++ application. I'm not very familiar with it though so I'll do some investigating.

Comment: Also, are you aware of a way I could just create char*** using the "unsafe" options?

Comment: I tried combining these in a variety of ways aside from marshalling or serializing.

I was close with just creating a windows CLR form, but it wont let me do threading in my C++ code then...

Comment: You don't have to use a file in order to achieve serialization.  You could just serialize the datatable to a string and pass that.  Also, dumb question but did you look at that link I provided?  Seems like it goes a long way to what you are trying to do.

    // Using gcroot, you can use a managed type in
    // a native class.

Comment: I'm going to look at serializing this a little more but at that point I'm thinking it would be faster to simple load the data in both c++ and c# separately from the original data source..

I did look at the link you provided, but to have a CLR class with statements like 'using namespace System;' I have to remove all threading from my original c++ I believe. Since I have a DLL wrapper class though I'm considering just doing it there if possible.

It seems like there should be a simple way to use C# front end and C++ backend code since C++ can process my data 10x faster than C#.